# Is there a way to disallow the default constructor of a specific class with EsLint?

Tags: function, syntax, constructor, eslint

For example:
I have a class "Dog" in typescript. I want an error everytime there is an occurence of the default constructor "new Dog()" in the code.
Is this possible with EsLint and how can I do it?
Thanks in advance.

I experimented a bit with 'no-restricted-syntax' but it didn't lead anywhere and I am not sure how to proceede.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track by using the 'no-restricted-syntax' rule. Here's how you can use it for your case:

```
"rules": {
  "no-restricted-syntax": [
    "error",
    {
      "selector": "NewExpression[callee.name='Dog']",
      "message": "<YOUR_CUSTOM_MESSAGE_HERE>"
    }
  ]
}
```